# Group by and having In OR condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**Note** (deptid = 2,3) or (deptid = 1 and sum(total cost)=0)

```
select * 
into employee1 
from employee2 
where empid in (select distinct empid 
                from employee3 e3 
                join employee2 e2 on e3.empid = e2.empid
                where e3.deptid in (2,3) 
                   or (e3.deptid = 1 
                group by empid, cost  
                having sum(e2.cost) = 0))
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Query have several errors ..`(e3.deptid = 1` doesnt have close parenthesis. And `group by xxxx` doesnt have a field.

Comment: actually i want to implement a condition like below..                                                                                                 (deptid = 2,3) or (deptid = 1 and sum(total cost)=0)  .....................cost column belongs to employee3 and deptid belongs to employee2

Comment: This is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I want those result where deptid in (2,3) or (dept =1 and sum of cost = 0) group by empid.........Please help Thanks....

Comment: We will help but you need help us understand the problem. Read Sean Lange link and please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a big guess. And those are the issue I have.

1. That query probably return multiple result so cant use `INTO employee1`
2. `employee3` looks like should be `depatment` table

I create a cte to calculate the cost for each employee first.  Then validate the department.

```
WITH ecost as (
    select e.empid, SUM(e.cost) as cost
    from employee2 e
    group by e.empid
)
select e.empid
from ecost e
inner join employee3 d
       on e.empid = d.empid           
where 
   d.deptid  in (2,3)
or (d.deptid = 1 and e.cost = 0)
```